# WKCrownDelegate doesn't seem to be working with Xcode 9 GM

Tags: xcode, watchos

I've tried the code below targeting both iOS 10.0/Watch OS 3.0 and iOS 11.0/Watch OS 4.0, and tested both in the simulator and my Watch OS 4 device. Nothing seems to trigger the `crownDidRotate` delegate method.

Simple interface with one label connected to the outlet. I know it's connected because I change the text in the `awake` method. Breaking in the delegate method never stops when I rotate the crown.

Any ideas?

```
import Foundation
import WatchKit
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WKCrownDelegate {
    var value = 1
    @IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        label.setText("Yeah?")
        crownSequencer.delegate = self
        crownSequencer.focus()
    }
    func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {
        label.setText("Rotational: \(rotationalDelta)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same experience.  As a hack, I added another call to crownSequencer.focus() in willActivate(), and I'm now seeing events. (xcode 9.0 gm, ios 11.0 gm, watchos 4.0 gm)

Answer (score 1):

Adding *crownSequencer.focus()* in *willActivate()* did not help me in Xcode10.
You don't have to call *crownSequencer.focus()* neither in *awake()* or in *willActivate()* but in ***didAppear()***. So you need to add the following lines:

```
override func didAppear() {
    super.didAppear()
    crownSequencer.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve it that simply. I needed to add a delay to reestablish focus on the crown as follows:

```
-(void)delayDo{
     self.crownSequencer.delegate=self;
     [self.crownSequencer focus];
}
-(void)didAppear{
     [self performSelector:@selector(delayDo) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
}
```